# Abstract Class, OOP

Tags: java, oop

Which of the below statements indicate that we should declare a class abstract?

Select one:

a. The class is too generic to represent a real world object

b. The class has child classes that need to implement some behaviors with their own specific implementation

c. The class only has constructor, getter / setter methods without any business behaviors.

d. The class has at least one abstract method

e. Options b and d only

f. Options a, b and d

I had this question on a test and chose an incorrect answer.  I believe the question is worded oddly but would like to know what the correct answer is and why.

Comment: Option F is correct although there are some religious debates about A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would go with option f.**
As:
a) If it isn't a real world object, you would never have to initialize it directly.
b) You could also use a non-abstract class or an interface for that, if the behaviours differ greatly. So this may be a little bit of subjective.
c) That may be the description of a POJO / JavaBean, but doesn't have to do with abstract classes.
d) If you have an abstract method you don't implement, making the class abstract is a *must*.

Though I must say, that this question is kind of subjective and the answer may also be e), depending on your professors opinion. But the stress on that it isn't a "real" thing in a) seems like it must be f).

Answer (score 0):

**I think option e.**

Reasoning:

a) I think being too generic to represent a real wold object would suggest a different problem with your OOD model, and not one that simply being abstract would solve.

b) Yes. Especially because it says, "...need to implement ***some*** behaviors...", as some of the behaviors (methods) will have implementations and others will not, that suggests abstract class, unless you factored the unimplemented behaviors out into interfaces. But in general, a key indicator of an abstract candidate is that you want to bundle some implemented behaviors with unimplemented actions (abstract methods).

c) This would make it a candidate for a POJO but not an abstract class. Being abstract is not needed for this.

d) Yes. If it has an abstract method it won't compile unless the class is declared abstract.